# Why is gravity the weakest force if, theoretically, it is made up of all the other forces' fields?

Tags: forces, gravity, mass, field-theory

I'm *quite* new to the physics world and want to get an idea as to how physicists have been able to sum all fields/forces (higgs boson, electromagnetic, weak force, strong force etc) in a said object, and determine that this summation is equal to the object's gravitational field.

From what I've heard, I have understood that you can calculate (through mass-energy equivalence) these individual forces' mass counterpart and some how summate them to determine the "net" mass - which is *somehow* related to the gravitational "field" of said object. Now, I know this makes no sense to me, especially considering that gravity is the weakest of the forces (how can all forces summated give the weakest one?) and how these calculations/conclusions be made. 
Anyone who can link me to an article concerning this, or has an explanation, thank you very much.

Comment: Um... who said that the summation of all those forces yields gravity?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction   ,    https://opentextbc.ca/physicstestbook2/chapter/extended-topic-the-four-basic-forces-an-introduction/

Comment: @nielsnielsen - Why not, if the no-hair theorem (for example) says that all black hole can be completely characterized by only three externally observable classical parameters: mass, electric charge, and angular momentum? Why not, if the Equivalence Principle (for example too) was successful when justifies the similarity  between inercial mass and gravitational mass, regardless the others matter fields? Why not, if gravity is the only field directly proporcional to the mass? I think theses aspects are clear examples that denounce the synthesis of matter in gravity.

Answer (score 4):

Gravity is *not* made up of other forces. The gravitational field is *not* the sum of other fields, neither in Newtonian gravity nor in Einstein’s General Relativity.

Interaction energies due to forces *do* contribute to the mass of an object. But so does its internal kinetic energy. And so does the rest energy of its constituent elementary particles. So the mass of an object is not completely explained by forces.

You could have gravity without having *any* other kind of force. In fact, cosmological models more or less ignore the other three fundamental forces.

Finally, Einstein discovered that mass isn’t really what produces gravity. Gravity is produced by energy and momentum.